# Yii infinite (endless) scroll using Active Record

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, pagination, infinite-scroll

I need to develop infinite scroll mechanism  - to fetch data from DB (Active Record) with ajax. Now in my project I  have pagination using CPagination Class and WidgetLinkPager in my view.
In my Controller/Model:

```
 $count = $this->count($criteria);
 $pages = new CPagination($count);
 $pages->pageSize = $per_page;
 $pages->applyLimit($criteria);
 $cars = $this->findAll($criteria);
 return array(
            'cars'    => $cars,
            'pages'   => $pages,
            'count'   => $count,
 );
```

In My View:

```
<? $this->widget('WidgetLinkPager', array(
        'pages'          => $pages,
        'perpageOptions' => $perpageOptions,
        'objectsCount'   => intval($searchResultCount),));
?>
```

My question is: how can i implement  infinite scroll and ajax with CPagination class? I need to render data on server - as it now works. And I have a lot of Params in url that i need pass through ajax to this action. I need to grabe them from url by javascript and pass using ajax. This params need to form search criteria.
I am thinking about using CListView widget - but it needs DataProvider object.

Thanks in advance.
Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an extension called [yiinfinite-scroll](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiinfinite-scroll/) that lets you do that!

Here's the example from there page:

The controller:

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
            $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
            $total = Post::model()->count();

            $pages = new CPagination($total);
            $pages->pageSize = 20;
            $pages->applyLimit($criteria);

            $posts = Post::model()->findAll($criteria);

        $this->render('index', array(
                'posts' => $posts,
                'pages' => $pages,
            ));
    }
}
```

And the view:

```
$this->widget('ext.yiinfinite-scroll.YiinfiniteScroller', array(
    'itemSelector' => 'div.post',
    'pages' => $pages,
));
```

Comment: You're welcome! If it solves your problem then you should mark the answer as resolving your problem!